How to join skirt to LOD terrain mesh chunk to ensure it matches at seams?
I am exporting my Unity terrain to a mesh. Because the terrain is big, I also split it into multiple chunks.
Moreover, I also generate chunk LODs. I enable a certain chunk LOD in-game based on the player's distance to that chunk.
The issue is that I get gaps when two chunks that are in different LOD levels try to connect. So I essentially need for every lower than LOD_0 chunk mesh to have a border that is the density of the LOD_0 mesh.
https://i.imgur.com/AcWxzMU.png
I have started writing the new mesh generation code, and this is what I have so far:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Sirenix.OdinInspector;
using Unity.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshStitchGeneration : MonoBehaviour
{
    private struct BorderData : IDisposable
    {
        public NativeList<Vector3> borderVertices;
        public NativeList<int>     borderTriangles;

        public static BorderData Null => default;

        public BorderData(Allocator allocator)
        {
            borderVertices = new(allocator);
            borderTriangles = new(allocator);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            borderVertices.Dispose();
            borderTriangles.Dispose();
        }
    }

    [SerializeField] private Mesh lod0Mesh     = null;
    [SerializeField] private Mesh lowerLODMesh = null;
    [SerializeField] private Material material = null;

    [Button("Generate")]
    private void Generate()
    {
        var newObj = new GameObject("Generated");
        
        newObj.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);

        newObj.transform.SetLocalPositionAndRotation(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

        var filter = newObj.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        var renderer = newObj.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

        renderer.sharedMaterial = material;

        using var borderMeshData = GetBorderMeshData();
        var newStitchedMesh = AppendBorderDataToMesh(in borderMeshData);

        filter.sharedMesh = newStitchedMesh;
    }

    private BorderData GetBorderMeshData()
    {
        if (lod0Mesh == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No lod0Mesh assigned!");

            return BorderData.Null;
        }

        var bound = lod0Mesh.bounds;

        if (bound.size.x != bound.size.z)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Requires a square mesh!");

            return BorderData.Null;
        }

        var vertices = lod0Mesh.vertices.AsSpan();
        var triangles = lod0Mesh.triangles.AsSpan();

        var gridSize = Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.Sqrt(vertices.Length));
        var vertexIncrement = bound.size.x / (gridSize - 1);

        var data = new BorderData(Allocator.Persistent);
        var vertexIndexMapping = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 vertex = vertices[i];

            var ox = bound.min.x;
            var oz = bound.min.z;

            if (vertex.x < ox + bound.size.x - vertexIncrement
                && vertex.z < oz + bound.size.z - vertexIncrement
                && vertex.x > ox + vertexIncrement * 2
                && vertex.z > oz + vertexIncrement * 2)
            {
                continue;
            }

            vertexIndexMapping[i] = data.borderVertices.Length;
            data.borderVertices.Add(vertex);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3)
        {
            int v1 = triangles[i];
            int v2 = triangles[i + 1];
            int v3 = triangles[i + 2];

            bool isV1OnBorder = vertexIndexMapping.ContainsKey(v1);
            bool isV2OnBorder = vertexIndexMapping.ContainsKey(v2);
            bool isV3OnBorder = vertexIndexMapping.ContainsKey(v3);

            if (isV1OnBorder || isV2OnBorder || isV3OnBorder)
            {
                if (isV1OnBorder) data.borderTriangles.Add(vertexIndexMapping[v1]);
                if (isV2OnBorder) data.borderTriangles.Add(vertexIndexMapping[v2]);
                if (isV3OnBorder) data.borderTriangles.Add(vertexIndexMapping[v3]);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    private Mesh AppendBorderDataToMesh(in BorderData borderData)
    {
        if (lowerLODMesh == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No lowerLODMesh assigned!");
            return null;
        }
        var newMesh = new Mesh();

        var lowerVertices = lowerLODMesh.vertices;
        var lowerTriangles = lowerLODMesh.triangles;

        var combinedVertices  = new List<Vector3>(lowerVertices.Length + borderData.borderVertices.Length);
        var combinedTriangles = new List<int>(lowerTriangles.Length + borderData.borderTriangles.Length);

        combinedVertices.AddRange(lowerVertices);

        foreach (var borderVertex in borderData.borderVertices)
        {
            combinedVertices.Add(borderVertex);
        }
        combinedTriangles.AddRange(lowerTriangles);

        int lowerVertexCount = lowerVertices.Length;

        foreach (var triangleIndex in borderData.borderTriangles)
        {
            combinedTriangles.Add(lowerVertexCount + triangleIndex);
        }
        newMesh.vertices  = combinedVertices.ToArray();
        newMesh.triangles = combinedTriangles.ToArray();

        newMesh.RecalculateNormals(); newMesh.RecalculateBounds();

        return newMesh;
    }
}

The above code is currently just for testing so I apologize if it is not the best in quality. What I am doing right now is getting a border from the LOD_0 chunk mesh. That part is working great. Now I need to merge that border data with the lower LOD chunk mesh.
Currently what I have done inside the "AppendBorderDataToMesh" function just simply creates a new mesh that contains the border mesh and the chunk mesh. So just two meshes in one.
So like it can be seen in this image: https://i.imgur.com/Nkii36k.png
But that is not what I need. I want to create new triangles that connect the border mesh to the chunk mesh by essentially forming quads between the vertices of the border and the closest edge vertices of the chunk mesh.
So something like this I guess: https://i.imgur.com/gs9ko1y.png
This is quite complex and I am not sure how to do it.
Can someone please help me? Would really appreciate it

That's quite a difference in density! Is this just one LOD level difference, or are you jumping down several levels in this example?

In this example, It's just one. My plan was to create several chunk LOD meshes. Having the 127x127 vertices per line for LOD 0, 63x63 for LOD 1, and all the way to 5x5 lowest LOD mesh.
In the image, the border is 127x127 and the chunk mesh is 5x5.
I always want to have the border of the highest LOD mesh in every lower LOD chunk mesh.
Perhaps going from 127 all the way to 5 vertices per line is too many LODs and too much of a change in density?

It's just that it decreases the gains you get from  LOD-ing down if you keep all those tiny triangles even in the 5x5 case. Would you be open to other options for disguising the seam that don't involve always keeping full-res borders? And are you generating these LODs on the fly/as needed, or are you running this code at edit time then building the resulting meshes into your game as fixed assets to load?

Yeah, it does seem redundant to have such borders, to be honest. I am exporting the Unity terrain from within the editor, in edit mode. The script takes the scene terrain(-s) and slices them into predefined-size chunks. It creates LODs and saves meshes to a folder by also marking these generated chunks as addressable, so they can be easily loaded during runtime by the world streamer. I am definitely open to other options, instead of having these borders. One thing I saw some people do was lower the distant low-detail chunks in the Y position. But I am not sure if that would fix the problem.

The following YouTube tutorial (Godot) contains the problem you are asking about (direct link to the problem in the tutorial): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AK951MB9kXM&t=610s
I have created my own implementation following the ideas outlined in that tutorial. However like the tutorial, I am generating flat meshes then using a Vertex shader to adjust the high of the points (by sampling a height map image).
In my case the LOD's are powers of 2, hence at a boundary between meshes the higher detail mesh has additional Vertexes which don't have a peer (to line up with) on the lower detail mesh. Hence all edge vertexes for the higher detail mesh can be considered: Paired or Unpaired.
No special handling is required for Paired vertexes, for Unpaired vertexes I average the height of the two Paired vertexes on either side - since that will create a straight line between the vertexes - that do exist in the lower detail mesh.
The only additional complication is that the vertex shader needs to know which (if any) of the sides of the mesh have an LOD drop off, I do this algorithmically, based on the distance from the player - the players position is passed as a shader parameter.
The same technique should work if you are generating static meshes, i.e. not manipulating them with a Vertex shader.
